# Split and retain character of split python

Tags: python, split

I want to split a string bases on 4 criteria [ a, p, :, -], and additionally convert string with only numbers into integers.

```
import re
DATA =  "12:30pm-12:00am"
print (re.split('[-:ap]',DATA))
```

Input string : "12:30pm-12:00am"

Desired output array:

```
[ 12, ":", 30, "pm", "-", 12, ":", 00, "am"]
```

[Full disclosure] This is from a coderbyte challenge. I am sorry if this is so noob it offends you, thank you for your patience.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
filter(None, re.split('(-|:|am|pm)', '12:30pm-12:00am'))
```

Start with this, it will guide you to the solutions, this will give you the desired output to start with:

```
['12', ':', '30', 'pm', '-', '12', ':', '00', 'am']
```

Note that the input is string, and in your post you posted the numbers as integers.